# Find Maximum Version from List of Files

Tags: python, sorting, max, unique

I need some python coding help on my Linux system please.

I’m trying to sort through a directory that has around 30 files.  Most of the files are duplicates but are incremented each time new code is developed.  I need to pick the max version for each group of files.

I need to grab the highest version for AzMesa, AzChandler, and AzPhoenix from the list of files shown below.  The version number always follows the second “-“ and is before the period ".".  This format does not change although at times the cities change, but it always starts with Az, always ends in rpm, and on occasion the "13.13" will increase as we release code.

```
AzMesa-13.13-1.x86_64.rpm
AzMesa-13.13-2.x86_64.rpm
AzMesa-13.13-3.x86_64.rpm
AzChander-13.13-1.x86_64.rpm
AzChander-13.13-2.x86_64.rpm
AzPhoenix-13.13-1.x86_64.rpm
AzPhoenix-13.13-2.x86_64.rpm
AzPhoenix-13.13-3.x86_64.rpm
AzPhoenix-13.13-4.x86_64.rpm
AzPhoenix-13.13-5.x86_64.rpm
```

The code below captures all the files that start with “Az” and ends in “rpm”.  It then prints out the package name and also prints out the version.

```
for name in glob.glob('Az*.rpm'):
  Package,Trash,CombinedVersion=name.split("-")
  print Package

  Version,Trash,Trash2=CombinedVersion.split(".")
  print Version
```

I need a way to only capture one file from each group that has the highest version number and send that output to a file.

Any help would be appreciated.  I do not claim to be a python developer, just trying my best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python structure dict, which hold key-value pairs, and convert version to tuple of ints, so it's comparable.

```
newest = dict()

for name in glob.glob('Az*.rpm'):
    #don't throw away the 13.13 - make one version
    package, combined_big_version, combined_version = name.split("-")

    #split the big vesrion into parts
    big1, big2 = combined_big_version.split(".")
    small_version, trash, trash2 = combined_version.split(".")

    #convert into a tuple of ints so we can compare them (biggest version first)
    #for example (13, 13, 1) < (13, 13, 2)
    #but         (13, 14, 1) > (13, 13, 4000)

    version = (int(big1), int(big2), int(small_version))


    #add to dictionary, or update if newer
    #store tuple (version, name) so we can get the name back 
    if not package in newest: 
        newest[package] = (version, name)
    else:
        newest[package] = max (newest[package], (version, name))
```

Then you can do:

```
for package in newest.keys():
    print package, newest[package]

# AzMesa (13, 13, 3)
# AzPhoenix (13, 13, 5)
# AzChander (13, 13, 2)

print list(newest.items())

# [('AzMesa', (13, 13, 3)), ('AzPhoenix', (13, 13, 5)), ('AzChander', (13, 13, 2))]


# get the file names
names = [newest[key][1] for key in newest]
print (names)

# ['AzChander-13.13-2.x86_64.rpm', 'AzPhoenix-13.13-5.x86_64.rpm', 'AzMesa-13.13-3.x86_64.rpm']
```

Comment: This works great and I appreciate your help.  By chance is there a way to capture the "name" of the file for the highest version?  I was looking at ways to compile the file name from the list but thinking if I can simply store the "name" in your code it would be easier.

At the end of the day I need to get the three file names with the highest versions.

Comment: Edited code to remeber the filenames by storing tuple (version, name) instead of just version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem: how to sort rpm versions and find highest version number: if you have a list of versions like this in a file 'mylist', e.g. from curl -s  (each version in separate line):

> 2.1.1-10
> 2.1.1-2
> 2.1.1-1
> 2.1.1-0
> 2.10.1-0
> 2.3.1-0
> 2.2.1-0
> 1.2.1-0
> 1.3.10-0
> 1.3.2-0
> 10.3.2-0
> 1.3.1-0
> 1.3.1-1

you can use shell commands to create proper order:

```
 awk '/^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+$/  { t=$0; sub("-",".",t); print t, $0 }' mylist  | sort -t . -n -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Basically it prepends a key string with only dots, then uses sort -t . to sort it, finally print original string.